# how can i get value from event in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my function that i use in my login component so that when i change my email it changes it value

```
   handleChange =e=>{
    //clone
    let username = {...this.state.username};
    //edit
    username = e.currrentTarget.value;
    //change state
    this.setState({username});
}
```

and i call this function in the following lines

```
          <form onSubmit ={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
            <input
             value= {this.state.username}
             onChange = {this.handleChange}
             type="email" 
             className="form-control" 
             id="exampleInputEmail1" 
             aria-describedby="emailHelp"/>
            <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
        </div>
```

so i get this errors

```
Warning: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
at input
at div
at form
at Login (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:831:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:33026:5)
at main
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:238:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:32959:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:32474:5)
```

Comment: have you tried e.target.value?

Comment: This might sound silly, but sometimes the local server / bundler might not have caught your changes.  I don't see a problem right away with your code, is it worth stopping your dev server, making sure all files are saved, and restarting the `npm run dev` command or whatever your using to start up the application?

Comment: i tried it and it worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so that's not an error. You need to use a connected component in this case.

```js
<input
  value={this.state.username}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  type="email"
  className="form-control"
  id="exampleInputEmail1"
  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
/>
```

For some reason, the `this.handleChange` seems `null` or `undefined`.

Show us your full code for debugging. Alternatively, try using:

```js
<input
  value={this.state.username}
  onChange={handleChange}
  type="email"
  className="form-control"
  id="exampleInputEmail1"
  aria-describedby="emailHelp"
/>
```

Also, remember, there could be some cached error messages, so refresh once.

This is not an error, it's just a warning.

You can either use `e.target.value` or whatever you're using now.

```js
handleChange = e => {
  // also you're not using it right.
  // because username is just a string value not an object.
  // let username = { ...this.state.username };
  // it should be:
  let username = this.state.username;
  //edit
  username = e.currrentTarget.value;
  //change state
  this.setState({ username });
};
```

Kindly see the above code block for comments on where you went wrong.

Comment: acctually it workded fine the wrong things was currentTarget it should've been target only as u mentioned and the object part as well thanks a lot

Comment: though i get another weird warning    .........................Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?
    at label
    at div
    at form
    at Login (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:831:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:33026:5)
    at main
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:238:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:32959:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:32474:5)

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal Just change `class=""` to `className=""` - `class` is a keyword in JavaScript. `:)`

Comment: @AbdelrahmanKamal That `target` vs. `currentTarget`: Check this out: https://joequery.me/code/event-target-vs-event-currenttarget-30-seconds/